# Aligning rectangular grid with raster pixels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, vector-grid, alignment

I want to create a 1000m grid over a 1000m land cover map such that the grid cells are perfectly aligned with the raster pixel underneath. But when I use the Create Grid function in QGIS, the cells and pixels are misaligned (understandably). The screenshot below illustrates this problem. What can I do to align the cells and pixels?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Possibiliy: create grid based on raster layer**

Make sure your grid is created in the same CRS as the raster layer. Set the `Grid extent` to the extent of the raster layer (click `...` next to this field) and choose the same horizotal and vertical pixel size (copy this information form the layer properties of the raster layer):

[image]

**Senond possibility: Raster pixels to polygons**

As an alternative, you can run `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Raster pixels to polygons`. The resulting polygons will also contain the pixel value of one of the raster's bands. For huge rasters, processing can take a while.

Comment: I'm already doing all that :( problem is that the grid extent is a rectangle around the raster layer and not the raster itself, and that seems to be causing the misalignment

Comment: OK, this is important information that should be included in the question! So maybe the raster is not in its original CRS? Can you add more information or provide your data for testing?

Comment: Try `Raster pixels to polygons`, see updated answer

Comment: The second method works. Thanks!